# Running Liquibase with CDI on Wildfly 8

Tags: cdi, liquibase, wildfly-8

I am trying to run Liquibase scripts using CDI  on WildFly 8.1.0.Final and I am getting this error:

```
Unsatisfied dependencies for type ResourceAccessor with qualifiers @LiquibaseType
```

My POM has these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mattbertolini</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My CDI Bean is as follows:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibaseConfig;
import liquibase.integration.cdi.annotations.LiquibaseType;
import liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor;
import liquibase.resource.ResourceAccessor;

public class LiquibaseStarter {
    @Produces
    @LiquibaseType
    public CDILiquibaseConfig createConfig() {
        CDILiquibaseConfig config = new CDILiquibaseConfig();
        config.setChangeLog("liquibase/parser/core/xml/simpleChangeLog.xml");
        return config;
    }

    @Resource(name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS")
    private DataSource ds;

    @Produces
    @LiquibaseType
    public DataSource createDataSource() {
        return ds;
    }

    @Produces
    @LiquibaseType
    public ResourceAccessor create() {
        return new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(getClass().getClassLoader());
    }
}
```

My project is a simple WAR.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LiquibaseStarter` has no bean-defining annotation. Add `@Dependent` at class-level.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. Unfortunately the example provided by Liquibase site did not have this annotation.

   http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/cdi.html

Comment: It depends on the CDI spec level and on your configuration whether or not a bean-defining annotation is required. Presumably, the Liquibase example was written for CDI 1.0.

Comment: I can update the docs but don't use CDI enough to know for sure the change. Would I just add @Dependent to public class LiquibaseProvider?

Comment: Yes, that would do. It won't break anything for CDI 1.0, and it's the default solution for CDI 1.1+. It would help casual users, and for advanced CDI users it should be obvious when and how to replace the default.