# Running Liquibase with CDI on Wildfly 12

Tags: wildfly, cdi, liquibase

I am trying to run liquibase CDI integration on Wildfly 12 (JDK 10). While start up the following error shows up

```
10:27:30,291 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => ".war")]) - failure description: {
"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\".war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ResourceAccessor with qualifiers @LiquibaseType
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @LiquibaseType liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibase.resourceAccessor
  at liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibase.resourceAccessor(CDILiquibase.java:0)
```

I found a similar question here: [Running Liquibase with CDI on Wildfly 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964483/running-liquibase-with-cdi-on-wildfly-8) but the given solution did not work for me.

My Producer code is the same as on the liquibase website: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/cdi.html
    package de.xima.lag.system.database.liquibase;

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import liquibase.integration.cdi.CDILiquibaseConfig;
import liquibase.integration.cdi.annotations.LiquibaseType;
import liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor;
import liquibase.resource.ResourceAccessor;


@Dependent
public class LiquibaseProducer {

  @Resource
  private DataSource myDataSource;

  private static final String LIQUIBASE_MASTERFILE_PATH = "META-INF/liquibase/master.xml";

  @Produces
  @LiquibaseType
  public CDILiquibaseConfig createConfig() {
    CDILiquibaseConfig config = new CDILiquibaseConfig();
    config.setChangeLog(LIQUIBASE_MASTERFILE_PATH);
    return config;
  }

  @Produces
  @LiquibaseType
  public DataSource createDataSource() throws SQLException {
    return myDataSource;
  }

  @Produces
  @LiquibaseType
  public ResourceAccessor create() {
    return new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(getClass().getClassLoader());
  }
}
```

My maven pom looks like: 
    ...
    
       org.liquibase
       liquibase-core
       3.6.1

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
   <artifactId>liquibase-cdi</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
...
```

Does anyone has an idea?

**Update:** Already including the *liquibase-cdi* dependency to the project causes this error. So I guess it is not a problem with the producer class?

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly released a new version currently so I switched to Wildfly 13 and it worked. No ide